# CSS Stylesheet for Custom Joomla Template isn't showing

Tags: css, templates, joomla

So I have currently used basic html and css coding to create a website for a client. The template uploads to the extension manager but when I go to preview it, the page looks nothing like it's supposed to. None of the styles from my css stylesheet are showing up. I'm new to Joomla so some help for this newbie would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more information I will be glad to give it. Unfortunately I am unable to provide a link since the site isn't live yet but will give you guys links to some screen shots.

EDIT:

```
        <?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;


?>

<!Doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title> Deda's Couture</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/component.css">
            <meta="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <jdoc:include type="head" />
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/media/jui/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->



        </head>
            <body class="content">




                <header>

                        <div id="topbar">
                        <a href="#"><img width="40" height="30" src="images/drupal.svg" alt="" id="drupal"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img width="40" height="30" src="images/facebook-square.svg" alt="" id="facebook"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img width="40" height="30" src="images/instagram.svg" alt="" id="instagram"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img width="40" height="30" src="images/twitter.svg" alt="" id="twitter"></a>
                            <p>1-800-555-5252</p>
                                            </div>

                    <input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle">
                    <label for="menuToggle" class="menu-icon">&#9776</label>            




            <center><img src="images/logo.jpg"></center>
                <div id="nav">
                    <div id="nav_wrapper">
                        <!-- <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">NEW ARRIVALS</a></li><li>
                            <a href="#">APPAREL<img src="images/dropdownarrow.jpg"></a>
                                    <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">MENS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">WOMENS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">CHILDREN</a></li>
                                    </ul></li>
                            <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">SHOES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">SPECIALS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>

                        </ul> -->
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainnav" style="html5" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right menu">
            <h3 class="cbp-spmenu-open">Menu</h3>
            <!-- <a href="#">HOME</a>
            <a href="#">NEW ARRIVALS</a>
            <a href="#">APPAREL</a>
            <a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a>
            <a href="#">SHOES</a>
            <a href="#">SPECIALS</a>
            <a href="#">CONTACT US</a> -->
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mobilenav" style="html5" />
        </nav>



        <!-- <button id="showLeftPush">Show/Hide Left Push Menu</button><img id="menu-icon" src="images/menu-icon.svg"></button>
 -->


            <!-- <img src="images/topbanner.jpg" width="100%"> -->
            <section class="banner">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="banner" style="html5" /></section>



        </header>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <section>
                <p class="locate"><!-- HOME // APPAREL // WOMEN'S APPAREL -->
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumbs" style="html5"</p>
                <!-- <ul id="gallery">
                    <li>
                    <img src="images/productbox.jpg">
                    <p> LOREM IPSA DIPA </p>
                    <p>179.00</p></li>
                    <li>
                    <img src="images/productbox.jpg">
                    <p> LOREM IPSA DIPA </p>
                    <p>179.00</p></li>
                    <li>
                    <img src="images/productbox.jpg">
                    <p> LOREM IPSA DIPA </p>
                    <p>179.00</p></li>
                    <li>
                    <img src="images/productbox.jpg">
                    <p> LOREM IPSA DIPA </p>
                    <p>179.00</p></li>
                </ul> -->

                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="gallery" style="html5" />



<!--                <h2>HEADLINE</h2>

        <p class="primarycontent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin laoreet faucibus commodo. Cras consectetur ligula et leo rutrum, ac porttitor ipsum lacinia. Nulla volutpat nisl ante, id consequat diam faucibus efficitur. Duis quis placerat tortor. Aenean pharetra maximus bibendum. Donec posuere mauris at est efficitur hendrerit. In sodales nisi nec lorem sollicitudin aliquam.

Suspendisse vel blandit nulla. Vivamus fringilla tortor condimentum convallis vehicula. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam tempor quam sit amet auctor interdum. Vivamus condimentum mauris a odio scelerisque elementum. Etiam fermentum lorem id commodo placerat. Ut scelerisque nibh eu feugiat euismod.</p> -->
                <jdoc:include type="message" />
                <jdoc:include type="component" />

</section>
</div>



    <footer>

        <!-- <div id="bottom-nav">
            <nav>
            <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
            <a href="newarrival.html">NEW ARRIVALS</a>
            <a href="apparel.html">APPAREL</a>
            <a href="access.html">ACCESSORIES</a>
            <a href="shoes.html">SHOES</a>
            <a href="specials.html">SPECIALS</a>
            <a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a>
        </nav> -->
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="submenu" style="html5" />


            <img src="images/bottomlogo.jpg" alt="">
        </div>



            <p><span class="copyright">COPYRIGHT &copy 2015 DEDA'S COUTURE BY 3 | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span> <span class="credits">
        RESPONSIVE WEBSITE DESIGNED BY FREEDOM CREATIVE SOLUTIONS</span><p>
        </footer>

        <script>
            var menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
                menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
                menuTop = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s3' ),
                menuBottom = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s4' ),
                showLeft = document.getElementById( 'showLeft' ),
                showRight = document.getElementById( 'showRight' ),
                showTop = document.getElementById( 'showTop' ),
                showBottom = document.getElementById( 'showBottom' ),
                showLeftPush = document.getElementById( 'showLeftPush' ),
                showRightPush = document.getElementById( 'showRightPush' ),
                body = document.body;

        showLeft.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showLeft' );
            };

            function disableOther( button ) {
                if( button !== 'showLeft' ) {
                    classie.toggle( showLeft, 'disabled' );
                }


        </script>


        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I have tried turning SEF off as well.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/AxPUwDY.jpg

This is the link to the screenshot of the index.php file before submission.

Comment: But when I use developer tools to inspect the site. This is what it looks like --> http://i.imgur.com/0yoQHBR.jpg

Here's the end result for the site --> http://i.imgur.com/lI7gqdI.jpg

Comment: Can you post the actual index.php for your template?

Comment: @BrianBolli I've posted up my index.php file

Comment: You might want to check at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/